# If $A=\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, then $I= \langle x, y\rangle$ is not a cyclic $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let  $A=\mathbb{R}[x, y]$ be the ring of polynomials in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the ideal $I=\langle x, y\rangle$, generated by the polynomials $x$ and $y$, is not a cyclic $A$-module.

I was thinking that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ but $1 \notin I$ so $I$ cant be cyclic but i dont know
because if $1\in I$ then $I=A$ and $A$ cand be a A-module itself and then it will be cyclic but i dont know

Comment: I think this is probably a duplicate, hence not posting this as an answer -- but another approach is to observe that $I \otimes_{A} (A/I) \simeq I/I^2$ is a vector space over $A/I \simeq \mathbb{R}$ of dimension 2, implying that $I$ can't be generated as an ideal by only 1 element.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\langle x,y\rangle$ were generated by a single nonzero element, say $f\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Then $x=af$ and $y=bf$ for nonzero polynomials $a,b\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Since $y$ is irreducible, either $b$ or $f$ is a unit. We can rule out $f$ being a unit since otherwise we would have $\langle x, y\rangle=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ which is not true (you need to show that $1\not\in\langle x,y\rangle$). Thus $b$ is a unit so $f=b^{-1}y$. Then $x=ab^{-1}y$ which says that $x$ is divisible by $y$, a contradiction.